# Navigate from a C# Project Page to Javascript Project Page Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am stuck at this problem. I have two Projects in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT), one project is C# Windows Phone Project named "CSharp_App" and the other project is JavaScript Windows Phone Project named "JS_App". Both of the Projects are under a same solution.

Now, my question is, is it possible to navigate from the C# App to the JavaScript App?

Suppose I have MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs. I want to navigate from MainPage.xaml.cs to default.html - is it possible? Any help will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, within the same app you cannot navigate from a XAML page to an HTML page.

You can use the [WebView XAML control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) in your C# XAML app to embed HTML in your XAML application as a control. However the HTML is displayed as it is displayed in the browser and has no access to WinRT.

You can have two different apps, one C# and one JavaScript and have them [register to handle a custom URI scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) which you can [launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701484.aspx) to get from one app to the other.

But if you're trying to create a sort of hybrid XAML+JavaScript app, that isn't really supported for Windows Phone 8.1